# Best Practices написания wrapper'а для REST API

Tags: .net, vkontakte-api, facebook-api, odnoklassniki-api

Недавно столкнулся с необходимостью написать несколько своих <s>велосипедов-</s>оберток для сбора информации из открытых источников, в том числе из социальных сетей (VK, Odnoklassniki, Mail.Ru, Facebook...).
**Собственно, вопрос**: какие вы знаете толковые библиотеки (даже небольшие) для работы с REST API? Само собой с открытыми исходниками, которые вы считаете примером удачной архитектуры, красоты кода и удобства понимания. Желательно для .NET.
Теперь немного поясню:

1. Слишком простые вещи, которые по какой-либо форме запроса предоставляют простой доступ вида `ApiObject["JSON_Name"]["JSON_SubName"]` — да, интересны, но лишь с точки зрения вопроса «как красиво распарсить JSON или XML».
2. Библиотеки, полностью заменяющие структуру исходных объектов — это, имхо, уже обертка над оберткой, т.о. также не очень интересно, но если вы можете привести действительно хорошие примеры — буду рад.
3. Нужно что-то среднее между пунктами «1» и «2».

Открыл для себя неплохой [VK API для .NET](https://vknet.github.io/vk/), но хочется рассмотреть больше вариантов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть в сторону RestSharp
http://restsharp.org/
скрывает рутину отсылки/получения запроса, в ответе уже можно получать десериализованный объект, либо можно самому десериализвать, т.к. прозрачный доступ к "сырым" данным.
Вот пример с оф сайта:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
request.AddFile(path);

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

// or automatically deserialize result
// return content type is sniffed but can be explicitly set via RestClient.AddHandler();
RestResponse<Person> response2 = client.Execute<Person>(request);
var name = response2.Data.Name;

// easy async support
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});

// async with deserialization
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<Person>(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.Name);
});

// abort the request on demand
asyncHandle.Abort();
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что именно в вопросе понимается под RestAPI, если нужно "универсальное" решение - рекомендую посмотреть, как это сделано в [FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/)

Здесь используется механизм [Type Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509.aspx), аналога которому нет в C#, но ничего не мешает написать эту обертку в отдельной сборке и использовать из C# кода.